# Permission to library denied - PPTK viewer

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am looking for general advice for troubleshooting a 'permission to library denied' error such as the one shown below:

I am using a conda environment on ubuntu 16.04. This error has arisen whilst using the NVIDIA library for 3D processing, Kaolin (imported as kal).

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/chris/Documents/4yp/Data/my_kaolin/pointcloud_to_projection.py",
> line 9, in <module>
>     cloud = kal.visualize.show(points, mode='points')   File "/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kaolin-0.1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/kaolin/visualize/vis.py",
> line 71, in show   File
> "/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kaolin-0.1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/kaolin/visualize/vis.py",
> line 137, in show_pointcloud   File
> "/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pptk-0.1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pptk/viewer/viewer.py",
> line 53, in __init__
>     stderr=(None if debug else subprocess.PIPE))   File "/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line
> 800, in __init__
>     restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line
> 1551, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pptk-0.1.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pptk/viewer/viewer'
```

I installed the Kaolin library in an conda environemnt by downloading the source code and running `python setup.py install` command from the sources root. I have not explicitly installed pptk at any point. Some info about my environment:

```
- SHELL=/bin/bash 
- CONDA_SHLVL=2
- CONDA_PREFIX_1=/home/chris/anaconda3
- VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
- VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR=/home/chris/.virtualenvs
- CONDA_PREFIX=/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP
- CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/chris/anaconda3/bin/python
- PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-package
```

The program is launched in pycharm via the command:

```
/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/bin/python /home/chris/Documents/4yp/Data/my_kaolin/Classification/pointcloud_classification_combinedset.py
```

When I open pycharm with the conda environment, I do receive the following warning, I am unsure whether it is relevant.

```
/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/4YP/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/paths.py:60: UserWarning: IPython dir '/home/chris/.ipython' is not a writable location, using a temp directory.
```

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? How did you install the library, for example?

Comment: @AMC I have added some further information to the original post. Do let me know if there is any other information that would be helpful.